# Firebase Error : Failed to resolve : com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

> Error:com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6

When I am trying to add firebase real time database in my android project this error pops up what should i do?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add firebase-database to your application, you also need to add the firebase-core libraries (which you commented out).

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
 }
```

If you haven't done so, you also need to add rules to include Google services and Google's Maven repository.

Please read [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to find out more.